# How to specify timeout for a query using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-settings, connection-timeout

We have a session timeout for all queries using this:

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c statement_timeout=5000',
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However there is a query that takes much longer to run. I want to override the 5 second constraint for this specific query. How would I do this? I tried using `connection.alias` to separate the query types but I'm still confused.

Specifically, can someone elaborate what this article is describing with the `connection.alias` to limit different queries on the same server? https://medium.com/squad-engineering/configure-postgres-statement-timeouts-from-within-django-6ce4cd33678a

Answer (score 0):

You can override it via raw SQL right before running your query:

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SET statement_timeout = 123;")
```

Note that you'd probably want to set it back afterwards as that connection will keep the value until it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `statement_timeout=5000` in `settings.py` doesn't work for me with **Django 3.2.16** on **Windows 11** but `statement_timeout=5000` works in **`test` view** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')
    cursor.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(10);')
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

*`cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')` only applies to **`test` view** rather than other views so you need to call `cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')` in each view if you want to apply `cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')` to each view.